# Select all where values equal 1?

Tags: php, mysql, select

It is the best way to select only records with "1" value? I cant make it works :/

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM codes WHERE php = 1 AND java = 1 AND ruby = 1 ORDER BY id ASC");

+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| ID   | CODES          |   PHP   |  RUBY  |  JAVA  |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 1    | ford           |    1    |    0   |    0   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 2    | seat           |    1    |    1   |    1   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 3    | fiat           |    1    |    1   |    0   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 4    | toyota         |    1    |    0   |    0   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 5    | chevrolete     |    1    |    0   |    1   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I think you want to use `OR` not `AND`.

Comment: Is your table called codes, not just your field?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Anyway, no real names or values ​​are, I just want to know how to create a successful query

Comment: You need to know that a whole line is a record. If you put `or` you'll get every single line since none of them has nothing but zeros. If you put `and` then your only result will be "seat". What exactly is the result you're looking for?

Comment: @vinodadhikary only OR?

Comment: @Ariane my real problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290265/php-trying-to-readdir-one-file-from-each-directory-or-sub-directory until I cant find any solution, I need to choose the records with value "1" and save them in an array, I guess.

Comment: Best practice would be to use the SET MySQL type (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html). Your application would be much easier to maintain, as you can add/remove values from the SET without changing the whole table structure (in contrast to adding/removing columns). Plus, the search would be much faster this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query won't work if your column is not an `int` so wrap the quotes around the values and try

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM codes 
           WHERE php = '1' AND java = '1' AND ruby = '1' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Ok, but if I use "and" I only get results with all "1" values​​? How do I get records with the values ​​"1" specific?

Comment: @santyas if you want to fetch the records where all the 3 languages have 1 than the above query will work, if you want to fetch records in which any of the one language has 1, than use OR instead of AND

Comment: Is it possible to save the result in an array automatically?

Comment: @santyas Sorry but didn't got you, what do you want to exactly

Comment: Imagine the value "1" represents the validation of an existing directory... I want to store the result of the query in a array, then show it with a "while or foreach" depending on the values ​​of the result. The contents of the array I should put it in a url. Example: `works/'.$ContentArray.'/'.$id.'/`

Comment: @santyas `mysqli_fetch_array()`?

Comment: yes, or mysqli_fetch_assoc works fine. But the only way to get data from the array is using this? `$php = $row['php'];` ?

Comment: Yea, that's how arrays are accessed. If you want "real" variables, use (with care) PHP's extract() function.

Comment: @santyas yea, what's wrong in using that? just use loop with `mysqli_fetch_array`, and simply echo the data using `$var['col_name']`

Comment: nothing wrong, i can run my code fine. But my principal issue is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290265/php-trying-to-readdir-one-file-from-each-directory-or-sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT codes FROM table_name WHERE php = 1 AND java = 1
```

The condition can be concatenated using AND/Or as pr required